# Node/Express - Otherwise Route and CORS

Tags: node.js, express, routes, cors

I'm getting a Node/Express API ready for production however have some questions/advice need help on:

1 - I'm using the npm package `cors` - did so for development to basically disable CORS, however now that I'm moving to production I only want certain URLS to be able to reach the API.

So to so this what I've seen is:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://www.example.com',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST']
};

app.get('*', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'});
});
```

However (from what I've seen) I'd need to do this for everyone request type e.g.

```
app.post('*', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
      res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'});
});

app.del('*', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
      res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'});
});
```

Is there an easier way to avoid such duplication?

2 - And the second question - I have a long list of API routes e.g.

```
router.post('/registerUser', function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to place some kind of 'otherwise' line so that if a route doesn't match anything I've defined i can return something specific?

Thanks.

Comment: For second question you can use following piece of code in your main file (this will gets executed if no route match):
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 // your custom response here
});`

Answer (score 1):

For first put cors as a middleware before your first route.

```
   app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    //routes down below
```

**Explanation:** Cors will be set for all the routes below for every request. As this middleware will be executed first.

For second put your otherwise or 404 route after your last route.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
   //Your message
   res.send('Page Not Found');
});
```

**Explanation:** If any route will not be matched then this route will trigger.

Comment: Thanks - i actually my routes defined in a separate file i.e `app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));` I tried to place the first bit of code above this line and the second after and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah - I think its actually working. Whats interesting is when I try on my browser it behaves as expected, but on Postman, it always works, even if i set the origin URL to something random. Is this because that app sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? And if thats the case, couldn't anyone technically do that?

Comment: No, it's the browser which checks your domain and the requested API domain, and restricts frm accessing the content. But if it finds Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header then it allows it web app to access it.

Comment: Postman does not imply such checks, it simply hit the url and display the response content

Comment: In fact, if you only hit you API with browser, it will display the content. But if you hit your API within some web app which is from different domain then it wont let your access the response data.

Comment: Don't fully understand - so if i use a random URL as the origin, my browser cannot access the API, but Postman can - why is that. So from what I understand, if Postman does not imply such checks what to stop someone from just hitting my API even if when trying on a browser they cannot?